# Why can anyone access my api deployed on heroku and how do i prevent it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I've always been interested in the frontend side until now. I'm new to node js. I am currently developing a mern-stack blog application. I have two folder backend and frontend. I have successfully deployed both of them in a link similar to this.

backend=> https://example-blog-backend.herokuapp.com/
frontend=> https://example-blog-frontend.herokuapp.com/

I do get, post, delete, patch etc. requests to my backend url.cBut i have a problem with security. Because anyone can access my backend api that I deployed from any computer and can see all my data. For example when I can access the data containing user information from the following link, if I can access it, everyone can. and that's ridiculous because he can see all my info.

https://example-blog-backend.herokuapp.com/users

```
{
 "userName": "alice",
 "password": "123567"
}
{
 "userName": "john",
 "password": "321123"
}
{
 "userName": "benjamin",
 "password": "123123"
}
```

https://example-blog-backend.herokuapp.com/posts

```
{
 "userId": 1,
 "id": 1,
 "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio"
 "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et 
 cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem 
 eveniet architecto"
},
{
 "userId": 1,
 "id": 2,
 "title": "qui est esse",
 "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea 
 dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis"
},
{
 "userId": 1,
 "id": 3,
 "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
 "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut 
 ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et 
 labore et velit aut"
},
{
 "userId": 1,
 "id": 4,
 "title": "eum et est occaecati",
 "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda 
 provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam 
 iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
}
```

I don't want anyone who knows my url address to see this information in json format. How can i solve this problem? How do you securely send requests to your backend and how do you deploy? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not provide any application-level security, I suggest you should implement some kind of authentication middleware like Passport.js in your application. Which can be easily paired with Express.js. There are multiple resources that you can use to implement this.

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314

For the sake of this question, you can just create a custom middleware, like passing a secret key or string and matching it exactly in your application.
Here is a sample:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var authToken = req.headers('AccessToken');
    if (authToken === 'Your-Own-Secret-Token') {
        next();
    }
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized Request');
})
```

After this, you will need to pass a Header named `AccessToken` in your request. make sure the value to be equal to `Your-Own-Secret-Token` or whatever you decide.